# PHP Date Convert day of year to date

Tags: php, date

Hi I'm trying ti convert a date from the day of the year let's say

```
$day_of_year=date('z');
```

in this case the result of

```
echo $day_of_year;
```

it will be 165 now what I need it is convert the 165 representation of a day to a date format j-M-Y how to do it?

Comment: `echo DateTime::createFromFormat('z', '165')->format('j-M-Y');`

Comment: great thank you  !